# Google maps api geocoding enabled, places and javascript show no errors, geocoding requests met w/ REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: react-redux, google-geocoder

The project is ruby on rails backend, react-redux frontend. I'm using the npm react-geocode. If I turn off website restrictions, the geocoding goes through. With the website restrictions on, however, it only works with Places and Maps Javascript API.

I've tried disabling and re-enabling. I've also tried various versions of syntax for the website restriction (e.g. 'https://fakesite.heroku.com/*' or 'https://*.fakesite.heroku.com/*') and I can only get Places and Javascript to not produce errors. My research shows that I don't need an API key but I'd like to keep it if possible to make sure no one is abusing my website (for tracking purposes).

This is the error message I'm receiving in the chrome console: 
'Error: Server returned status code REQUEST_DENIED'

I still get this error message, albeit fewer of them, when I put no restrictions on my API key. But the website does the geocoding as intended without the restrictions, despite the error messages.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  location: ""
};
this.handleGeocode = this.handleGeocode.bind(this);
this.checkAverage = this.checkAverage.bind(this);
Geocode.setApiKey("MYAPIKEY");
```

}

```
componentDidMount() {
const { spot } = this.props;
Geocode.fromLatLng(spot.lat, spot.long).then(
  response => {
    this.handleGeocode(response);
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error);
  }
);
```

}

```
handleGeocode(response) {
const location = response.plus_code.compound_code
  .split(" ")
  .slice(1)
  .join(" ")
  .split(",")[0];
if (this.state.location !== location) {
  this.setState({ location: location });
}
```

}

Comment: How do you call Geocoding service? Can you post example?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to format the code in comments so I added it to the original post

Comment: What is Geocode object? Is it wrapper for HTTP web services?

Comment: I think so, it's this npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geocode

Comment: API keys for web services don't support referrer restrictions. They support only IP address restrictions. If you need referrer restriction the only option is using Geocoder service of Google Maps JavaScript API v3. Have a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem